# Define global variable as hash

Tags: c++

I have a number of C++ classes, alot of them (not all) share two "static size variables" e.g.

share.h

```
/*Other variables in this header used by all classes*/

static size width=10;//Used by about 60%

static size height = 12;//used by about 60%
```

So I placed them in a header file along with other objects that all classes share.

when I compile the project I get alot of warnings (from the classes which dont use these), which complain about them being defined and not used. But I need them there!

So I ask, is there a way to hash these to prevent such warnings?

Hashing them so that they can be defined! preventing warnings from classes calling this header file which dont require these last two variables, but they call header because they need everything else init

Comment: Show some code and of course the warnings.

Comment: 1) If they are never used, why do you need them? 2) What has hashing to do with it?

Comment: I think I follow this, until you talk about a hash... what?

Comment: @Bjorn - I states (Most classes do use them, some dont)

Comment: The situation you describe is vague, but having external static description variables is a code smell.  You may be better off having `.Width()` and `.Height()` inline static functions in the classes, and having them refer to whatever you need.  That would allow you to reliably change values if necessary for a particular class.

Answer (score 2):

<sub><strike>**Edit** reading tune2fs' answer, I realized I may have interpreted the question wrong.</strike></sub>

Perhaps you forgot to use `extern` in the header file? If you just include `static` definitions in the header file ***all compilation units will have unique copies*, not shared**. See also [this explanation of `static`/`extern`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921946/changes-to-static-variable-goes-out-of-scope-c/5921971#5921971)

**Edit** Disambiguated in comments

---

```
 static SomeClass NotUnusedInstance;


 static void unused_vars_helper()
 {
      static SomeClass* take_address = &NotUnusedInstance;
 }
```

This approach is design to have minimal impact (not invoking any actual code; `take_address` isn't *actually* initialized unless you *call* unused_vars_helper).

This should work pretty well for your case. You can make `unused_vars_helper()` static and/or move it inside an anonymous namespace to prevent external visibility of the helper.

Comment: they need them to be unique for there own process, static is respected for this make

Comment: @Perl_noob: okay, than my original approach (_`unused_vars_helper`_) is correct for your use

Answer (score 2):

You should place them in an individual header file. So you can include it only in the classes they need it. This avoids the warning in the other classes. So in the end you will have two header files. One where the stuff for all classes is included and another where the variables which are not used in all are defined.

However try to avoid global variables.

Comment: I can see what you mean, but I feel an individual header for these two simple values is quite - welll - useless? wasteful?

Comment: I do not think so. As it makes clearer what you include where. It is much worse to include variables in all classes, as they are then more or less global variables, and they should definitely be avoided.

Comment: I fully agree with try not using globals, but in this case I dont see any other option apart form addeding these two lines of code to about 60% of my classes, which seems even more wrong :(

Comment: Your right that is even worser, therefore put them in an own header file and include it in the 60% of the classes where you need them. So in the end it is just a 60% global variable instead of a 100% :p